# How to publish a new post to facebook wall?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My app have been approved for `publish_actions` permission and I want to publish to user's wall behave my user. I tried to call the graph API like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/feed?access_token=<token>&method=post&message=Hello`

I read the facebook documents and It says `A user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts.`
  But actually I can't publish the message to user's wall. What I receive is:

```
    {
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token",
      "type": "FacebookApiException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 1732004,
      "is_transient": false,
      "error_user_title": "Invalid Access Token",
      "error_user_msg": "Invalid access token received.",
      "fbtrace_id": "<trace code here>"
          }
   }
```

Do I make any mistake?

**Update:** Add screenshot of my token debugger information 
[image]

Comment: you have to do a POST call, not GET...

Comment: I tried with Post method and got same result. BTW,  AFAIK, use GET request with parameter "method=post" will be considered as POST request.

Comment: then post your code, and debug your access token

Comment: I tested most Facebook graph apis with Web browser. No any source code. Whenever I can call the api with Webb rower,   the code behind will work

Comment: you are actually right, it works with the api to set the method parameter as GET parameter. worked fine for me, so there is only one thing: your access token is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=xxx&method=post&message=test

Make sure the Access Token is valid and includes the `publish_actions` permission, you can test it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token/

Comment: hmm, I update my question with attached screenshot, as you can see, the token is valid and have `publish_actions`. I can use this token to retrieve my feed, but Can't publish a new one.